# Load Balancing issue across the Cluster EJB calls in Weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

Our Application has 2 Clusters running in Weblogic 12 C.

Each Cluster 4 Managed Servers. Cluster B is making EJB Call to  Cluster A through Foreign JNDI . In Cluster A EJB Calls are not distributing across the managed server ? This results in overload of One Server in Cluster A. We are using round robin load balancing in Cluster Configuration.

Can you tell me any other configuration we can make in our Weblogic to make ejb calls get load balanced ?

Regards,
Sakumar

Answer (score 0):

It's like you need to set your Foreign JNDI URL to specify all of the hosts in the cluster. It doesn't matter if the cluster is load balanced if the client keeps calling the same host.

Instead of this, which will direct all traffic to one host:

```
java.naming.provider.url = t3://server1:port1
```

Try using:

```
java.naming.provider.url = t3://server1:port1,server2:port2
```

---

EDIT

It sounds like the weblogic algorithm is not doing what you want, look at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24425/load_balancing.htm#CLUST180

Specifically - `the round-robin algorithm cycles through a list of WebLogic Server instances in order`. So it's hitting the first server every time because that is the first in your list. I would recommend trying another algorithm or using an external load balancer

Comment: We are already using below URL t3://DMS-DD-2i:8001,DMS-DD-1i:8001,DMS-DD-2i:8011,DMS-DD-1i:8011, However Server is still initiating call to  DMS-DD-2i:8001

Comment: Edited with some more info that may help

Answer (score -1):

This turns out to be bug in weblogic where load balance algorithm fails for version based application ear deployment

Regards,
Sakumar